# issues with Python version when I am using conda install

Tags: python, conda

I tried to install optitype as follow:

```
conda install -c bioconda optitype
```

I got the message:

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

- optitype -> python[version='2.7.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|3.5.*|3.4.*']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

- feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
- feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0

Your installed version is: 2.31

So, I tried to install python 2.7 in conda:

```
conda install -c anaconda python=2.7
```

which gave me hundred of conflicts and finished by saying that I installed:

Your installed version is: 2.31

I re-tried to install optitype but it's not working!

If someone has an idea!

Comment: your python ver is still less than 2.7!! prolly that's where the issue is!! ALso can you just run **conda install python=2.7**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I tried conda install python=2.7 . It's still the same issue: a lot of conflicts ending with Your installed version is: 2.31. Not sure what can I do

Comment: could be a circular dependency issue.. you may have to fix those one by one i guess :(

Comment: wow ok thanks, it will be long. Those are an example of the conflict that I have:  Package pytz conflicts for:
pytz
pyzotero -> pytz
Package cryptography-vectors conflicts for:
pyopenssl -> cryptography[version='>=2.2.1'] -> cryptography-vectors=2.3
wheelThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0

Answer (score 1):

Bioconda as a channel builds atop the `conda-forge` channel. Any specification that does not prioritize that (such as prioritizing `anaconda` channel) is incorrect. Also, do not bother changing Python versions *in-place* beyond patches - nearly every package will have to be reinstalled, such that it is much more simple for the solver to create a new environment. Try something like,

```bash
# name the environment something meaningful (not "foo")
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge -c bioconda python=2.7 optitype
```

Feel free to include additional packages that you require in the same line.

Note that `mamba` is much faster than `conda`, especially when solving for older packages like this. That is, were I installing this, I would use:

```bash
# install mamba if not already installed
conda install -n base -conda-forge mamba

mamba create -n foo -c conda-forge -c bioconda python=2.7 optitype
```

Comment: Hi merv, Thanks a lot it working well!